# Message gets refused by Android Wear watch

Tags: android, wear-os

I'm working on an app that will display some data to the user on the watch interface. Both watch and mobile modules build and install on their respective devices, but when messages (which is how the watch receives its data) are caught by the watch I see the following in the logs:

`W/WearableService﹕ ensureBindStarted: app does not match record's app key:`

followed by what appears to be the package name for the apps and some sort of hash.

According to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24957860/onmessagereceived-not-called-in-wearablelistenerservice), the problem is caused by apps being signed by two different keys. While this seems plausible, I am running both just by clicking the play button in Android Studio and do not have signing configured for either. Is there some process I can undergo to ensure both are signed with the same debug key?

Comment: Can you post package names for both apps (mobile and wearable)? Are you sure that they are the same?

Comment: Positive. While I can't post it, I confired that both `build.grade` and `AndroidManifest.xml` files shared the same package name.