# WearableListenenerService onMessageReceived not called

Tags: java, android, wear-os

I have made a simple Service that should receive messages from wear:

```
public class serviceforwatchlock extends WearableListenerService {

    @Override
    public void onMessageReceived(MessageEvent messageEvent) {
        super.onMessageReceived(messageEvent);

        Intent intent = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);
        intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
        startActivity(intent);
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();
    }
}
```

I checked if the onCreate method is called and it indeed is.

Also, here is my manifest:

```
<service
            android:name=".serviceforwatchlock"
            android:enabled="true"
            android:exported="true">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="com.google.android.gms.wearable.MESSAGE_RECEIVED" />
                <data android:scheme="wear" android:host="*"
                    android:path="/start-activity" />
            </intent-filter>
        </service>
```

Now my wear code:

```
new Thread(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                NodeApi.GetConnectedNodesResult nodes = Wearable.NodeApi.getConnectedNodes( mApiClient).await();
                for(Node node : nodes.getNodes()) {
                    MessageApi.SendMessageResult result = Wearable.MessageApi.sendMessage(
                            mApiClient, node.getId(), "/start_activity", "lockscreenGTP".getBytes() ).await();
                }
            }
        }).start();
```

The onMessageReceived method does not get called and I also dont get any error message. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Based from this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24957860/onmessagereceived-not-called-in-wearablelistenerservice), one possible reason why you are encountering this is that your apps are signed with the different keys. Package names of phone and wearable apps are the same and they also need to share the same signature. Please make sure that you have both apps signed with the same key. It is also suggested in this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33817622/wearablelistenerservice-onmessagereceived-is-not-called-on-device) to check if `applicationId` was the same.

Comment: It is not a release version, so the application isn't signed with any key. I also confirmed that the package is the same.