# WearableListenerService not starting on release/production

Tags: android, wear-os, android-wear-data-api

I'am maintaining a project that has a a wearable subproject. I was fixing some bugs on it, and it was working fine.

However the app behaves very weird on `Release configurations`.

1. The MainAcitivty that implements `MessageApi.MessageListener`, has a method `onMessageReceived` which is never called. However when i create a sublclass of a `WearableListenerService` the `onMessageReceived` works fine.
2. The WearableListenerService on the Handheld is never awaken. I'am outputting logs, but the `onMessageReceived` is never called, which makes the communication between the two devices a mess.

The biggest `?` i have in my head is that how it can work when i run it on debug, but not when i sign it and make a release version.

I'am not getting any noticeable error messages from the log or anything, and i have double checked that the package name is the same for both of the apps.

Any help that will guide me to a solution is much appreciated, thank you.

Comment: I'm not posting this as an *answer*, because it's just something to check at  this point... The obvious thing that's changed between debug and release builds is the APK signature, and signatures have to match between handheld & wearable apps in order for the Message API to work. Are you certain that both devices have APKs signed with the same [release] cert?

Comment: I will try check up on this, thanks

Answer (score 1):

Check the **applicationId** is the same for both the mobile and wear apps.

Here is a similar question's [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24595170/sending-messages-from-android-wear-to-host-device).

Comment: He already said that he "double checked that the package name is the same for both of the apps." That's the same as the `applicationId`.

Comment: Somehow I missed that sentence in the question, reading too fast. Thanks for the catch. ;-)